# CityEngine: Displaying points

Tags: cityengine

I'm new with CityEngine and I'm currently trying to alter the display of a point dataset which are representing a number of sensors.

I am unsure of how to alter their height (obviously I don't want to extrude them) and also how to change the size! They are tiny! I've attached a screen shot as an example. I can't find much information on the internet for this...

[image]

As you can see, they aren't very well displayed! I have had to highlight one to make it obvious where they are, the rest look like specs.

I have also attached a screengrab of the attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question was asked quite some time ago the answers might still be of value to someone.

There are actually two questions asked here I think.

**How to alter the elevation of the objects?**
You can use the "move tool" (click the button on the top or use the 'w' key). Then pull on the vertical arrow to shift all the selected objects vertically.
There is a text field on the top that you can type the exact offset if you want to be that exact.

**How to display the points**
As you imported points into CityEngine it does only show you points. If you apply a rule to the point you can change the size of the visualization either using the [scope operation](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/topic/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/cgareference/op_s.html) `s(x,y,z)` and add any geometry you want to it so it is visualized - e.g. a cube using the [primitive cube operation](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/topic/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/cgareference/op_primitive.html#cube) (or `i("builtin:cube")` if you're not on CityEngine 2016.0 yet).
You stated that you don't want to extrude them. But there is no other way to give points a proper visualization than to create larger geometry.